# Java how to extract last digit of a integer then display to that number of decimal?

Tags: java

for example if user enters `133.66666`
it will return `133.666`.

```
155.88888888888
=155.88888

821.8765432
=821.8
```

Code:

```
Scanner keys = new Scanner( System.in );
double x = (int) keys.nextDouble();
double lastdigit=x%10;
```

This is how find the last digit
but how do I use the digit number to display the amount of decimal?

Sorry I wasn't clear enough
User can enter any number they want (assume they are all positive)
then I use the last digit of integer number X to display X amount of decimal

Comment: This `133.66666` is not an integer. Also, check out `NumberFormat`.

Comment: Actually, if the user enter `133.6666` it will return `133.0`.

Comment: @ZouZou Yeah, clearly he is trying to convey something else.

Comment: I can't understand your question. All these numbers are not integers. And I fail to see any common logic between your 3 examples: the first one keeps 3 decimals, the second one keeps 5 and the last one keeps 1. Rephrase your question and tell us what you're trying to achieve, in a clear way.

Answer (score 1):

use `setMaximumFractionDigits` to set no of decimal places

try

```
     BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(23.045345686);   
     int noOfDecimalPlaces= 5;
     DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
     df.setMaximumFractionDigits(noOfDecimalPlaces);
     System.out.println("bd value::"+ df.format(bd));
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering 155.88888888 is a `double`

```
double n = 155.888888888
int num = n;  // rounds down to 155
String numString = String.valueOf(num);
String last = numString.subString(
       numString.length() - 1, numString.length());
// should return 5
int lastDigit = Integer.parseInt(last);

// get new double
String formatted = String.forat("%." + lastDigit + "f", n);
double revisedN = Double.parseDouble(formatted);
```

Note: untested

If you just do `155 % 10`, you'd get `8`; but what if its just 1 digit like `5` (5.8888), then you cant use `% 10`, that's why I used the String value